# Scrapy: Rules with ignored extensions don't work

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, rules

Scrapy still saves links with extensions mentioned in ignored extensions of the scrapy framework. But why?

**On Console the links with depth 2 will be ignored:**

```
    020-12-07 15:39:46 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth] DEBUG: Ignoring link (depth > 2): https://www.th-koeln.de/weiterbildung/mit-medienkritik-gegen-fake-news-das-fakehunter-planspiel-als-bibliotheksangebot-fuer-jugendliche_78973.php
```

**But PDF Files, PNGs etc.. still don't ignored and so crawled:**

```
2020-12-07 15:39:46 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.th-koeln.de/mam/downloads/deutsch/hochschule/profil/nachhaltige_hochschule/umwelterklarung2019_web.pdf>
```

**Here is my code:**

```
class FullThSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'full_th_spyder'
# allowed_domains = ['www.th-koeln.de']
start_urls = ['https://www.th-koeln.de/']
custom_settings = {
    'DEPTH_LIMIT': 2
}

rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(deny_extensions=(IGNORED_EXTENSIONS)),
              follow=True), )



def parse(self, response):
    for link in response.css('a::attr(href)').extract():
         url = response.urljoin(link)
         if url.startswith('https://www.th-koeln.de'):
             yield response.follow(url, self.parse)
```

Comment: Your `parse` method iterates URLs from responses and follows them all, regardless of extensions.